# initialize multiple variables in one line SAS

Tags: variables, initialization, sas, assign

New SAS programmer here..in .NET we can assign one value to multiple variables in one line like so:

`var1 = var2 = var3 = 0;`

is there a syntax in SAS to do the equivalent?

Comment: You don't need to initialize SAS variables, what are you trying to do that requires initialization? If sum, use the SUM() function instead which will ignore missing values or lack of initialization.

Answer (score 3):

No.

But there are other ways to accomplish that type of thing.

Most common would be to use an ARRAY and a DO loop.

```
array varlist var1 var2 var3 ;
do i=1 to dim(varlist);
  varlist(i)=0;
end;
```

You could use the ARRAY statement to initialize the variables.

```
array varlist var1 var2 var3 (3*0);
```

But that only applies to the initial value on the first iteration of the data step.

Or you could be creative and use a macro function to generate the code.

```
%sysfunc(tranwrd(var1|var2|var3|,|,%str(=0;)))
```

If you want to set the values to missing you can use the CALL MISSING() function.

```
call missing(of var1 var2 var3);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, SAS doesn't support multiple assignment.

SAS evaluates `var1 = var2 = var3 = 0;` as `var1 = (var2 = var3 = 0);` and  returns a value of 1 for `var1` if `var2 = var3 = 0` and a 0 otherwise.